# Null pointer while using Persistent Store in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, persistent

i used these for storing data :

```java
value="1";  
FieldChangeListener listenerslider = new FieldChangeListener() {
    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {

        synchronized(store) {
            store.setContents(value); 
            store.commit();
        } 

        Dialog.inform("Success!");
    }
};
```

and these is for fetching that data

```java
synchronized(store) {
    String currentinfo = (String)store.getContents(); 
    if(currentinfo == null) {
        Dialog.inform("error");
    } 
    else {
        edtplasmasodium.setText(currentinfo);   
    }
}
```

// these one i used in both class

```java
  static PersistentObject store;
  static {
       store = PersistentStore.getPersistentObject( 0xa1a569278238dad2L );
  }
```

why ? i am getting null pointer while fetching data in second class or shall i want to use a real device for testing that functionality?

Comment: Can you do a 'fetch' immediately after your store to demonstrate that it has worked correctly.

Comment: currentinfo  is showing null

Comment: change to if(currentinfo.equals(null))

Comment: hay thanks @TheLittleNaruto i change it to if(currentinfo.equals(null)) and its done :)

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is.  Are you saying that it's a problem (an unexpected result) that `currentinfo` is ever null?  Or, are you just trying to decide what to do when it is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `if(currentinfo==null)`

to `if(currentinfo.equals(null))`

Comment: What?  How can this answer possibly help here?  If `currentInfo` is null, then your suggestion will throw an exception.

Comment: Actually it's not null, the way of comparison is wrong in case of String. @Nate I hope you understood.

Comment: I guess I don't understand.  The OP said it was null, and I still don't see how this answer does anything to stop it from being null, and will only crash his program if it really **is** null.

Comment: @Nate - that makes 2 of us.